# How to Customize the View of AutoCompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have AutoCompleteView where the user can search for other users. User is a custom object which consists of id, name. AutoCompleteView is controller by UsersAdapter. UsersAdapter handles setting the view of User Object in the suggestion. How do I set the AutoCompleteView to Search on the User name? I mean, autocomplete should work based on the username.

Comment: the easiest is to use a SimpleCursorAdapter with a FilterQueryProvider

Comment: Could you please explain your question clearly and tell the problem neatly

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `addTextChangedListener` on your AutoCompleteTextView.
After, use one of 3 methods provided to call another function which will treat your list which contains usernames.

Here an example :

```
recherche.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3)
        {
            if (charSequence.length() > 1)
                searchSuggestions(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
        }
    });
```

For the "search" method, you can find many examples, in my case, that's linked on a BDD, so I use an asyncTask, but if you already have a list stored, use the match function.

Hoope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
   mAutoCompleteTextViewStart = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etsource);
  mAutoCompleteTextViewDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etdestination);
   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mStringsStreet);
    mAutoCompleteTextViewStart.setAdapter(adapter);
   mAutoCompleteTextViewStart.setThreshold(1);
   mAutoCompleteTextViewDestination.setAdapter(adapter);

   <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/etsource"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Start"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```